# Create a remote tracking branch for local branch without communicating to remote

Tags: git

I have a local branch `A`. I need to create a remote tracking branch for it say `origin/A` . Is it possible to create it without communicating to remote ?

Comment: Debatable. If you mean "can I update my local repo state in the same way it would be updated by creating a remote tracking ref; but without contacting the remote", then sure - torek's answer has you pretty much covered. Whether that's *really* a remote tracking ref - since it isn't set by tracking anything that is or was on the remote - is a matter of semantics, but certainly git will recognize it as such.  So the real question is, what are you trying to do, that you think you can only do by manipulating git into lying to you?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger It's a theoretical enquiry trying to understand the  Git which might/might not be related to a practical problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Specifically, a *remote-tracking branch name* like `origin/A` is actually a *local* entity, and `git branch --set-upstream-to` or `git checkout --track` *uses* this local entity without contacting another Git.

Note, however, that names in the `refs/remotes/` name-space are *automatically created or updated*, and sometimes *automatically destroyed*, by `git fetch` and `git push`.  When fetching from, or pushing to, a *remote* whose name is `origin`, `git fetch` and `git push` will update the appropriate remote-tracking name(s) based on the fetch or push result.  More precisely, running `git fetch origin` will obey the `remote.origin.fetch` refspec.  The default refspec is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.  If the Git at the URL stored in `remote.origin.url` has an `origin/A`, this results in creating or updating `refs/remotes/origin/A` at that time.

If you use the `--prune` option or set any of the options that selects pruning—I configure `fetch.prune = true` sometimes, for instance—then this same `git fetch origin` will *remove* your own `refs/remotes/origin/A` if no `refs/heads/A` exists on the Git at `origin`.

Assuming you don't care about these automatic operations, there is only requirement that your own local Git imposes when your own Git goes to set the two-part fields for branch `A` so that its upstream is `origin/A`.  That requirement is that your local repository must *have* a reference named `refs/remotes/origin/A`.  If you don't have one yet, the command:

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/A <valid-commit-specifier>
```

will create it, without contacting the Git at the URL (and hence regardless of whether there is a `refs/heads/A` on that Git now).  It's not clear what you would like to use as a valid commit specifier here, though.  The ideal value would be whatever `refs/heads/A` resolves to on the Git at the URL stored under `origin` is, and to find that, you'd have to contact that Git.  But any valid commit specifier will do, if you don't mind `git status` producing bizarre ahead/behind counts.